# Delayed connecting flights

Tags: air-travel, british-airways

I am booking a flight from Delhi to Chicago via London with British Airways.

If the first flight gets delayed, would the airline provide me travel on another flight?

Comment: Generaly speaking, yes. And you can also get compensation based on eu law

Comment: Is your trip in a single booking? Usually this is an important factor. Separate bookings = you are on your own.

Comment: yes it's a single booking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you run into such a situation, for international flights if the delay is short the 2nd plane would wait for you. If not you'll get the next flight on the same day, and if not that you'll get free hotel, the plane next day and compensation.

Comment: You cannot count on an airline to hold a flight for you— they might so if a significant number of passengers were affected (or a less significant number of highly valuable passengers) and had no standbys, but there is no way they are going to hold a full 747 for even a minute. If every airline did so, it would be almost impossible for a large airport to run smoothly.

Comment: Planes delay all the time, especially in larger airports, and especially for passenger planes. Obviously they try to be on time, but situation dictates that it doesn't always happen. I travel internationally all the time, I can't even remember my last flight that was on time. And even if you leave the boarding gate "by the minute", you just end up behind a long queue of taxing and landing planes, which are managed as the current situation unfolds.